# Doctrine : how to handle family lists

Tags: doctrine

I have searched on the net but was not able to get an answer for my case. I am migrating a project on doctrine.

What is the correct way to link an entity to another entity that contains all the "families" of a project.

The families can be for instance :

- "project_status" : status1, status2, status3
- "countries" : en, us, cn ...
- "tags" : tag1, tag2, ...

So all these values are stored in the same table in database and my entity handle this.
So now i have an entity that can have for example several countries or tags.
In the database i have one text field for the countries and one text field for the tags. And i store the ids of each tag or family inside these fields.

So let's say that I have one entity called "family" and one entity called "myEntity".

What is the best way to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe I have found one way in fact.
Instead of using my usual text field in my entity table to store the ids of the families I will use a join table.

So let's say that I have one table with my different lists in my project (country, file_status, and other possible lists). I will then have one entity for this table "familyEntity".

I will create a table that will be used for the cases in which one entityA can have several values of the same family (country for instance). In that case, I wil have a many to many association between familyEntity and entityA for that family.
If I have another entityB that uses the family "status" with several values possible, I will also have a many to many association using the same table for the association.

In the other cases in which only one value is possible for one family I will have many to one association.

Don't know if it is the right way but it occured to me that way. This solution seems ok for primary keys that are not compound).